# Can not open a text file with the " fstream "

Tags: c++, c++builder, fstream

My current difficulties will open "My File.txt" using `fstream`.
in "My File.txt" there is a long sentence. so I use the `AnsiString` to accommodate the text that is inside

```
    void __fastcall TFormManager::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    AnsiString FileName, tmpText;
    FileName = "\conf\db\My Text.txt";
    if (FileExists(FileName)) {
        ifstream data(FileName);
        data >> tmpText;
    }
}
```

i use C++ Builder XE6. Thx

Comment: So please explain these "difficulties".

Answer (score 1):

Double the backslashes:

```
FileName = "\\conf\\db\\My Text.txt";
```

Comment: Or change them to forward slash: `"/conf/db/My Text.txt"`

Comment: I think it's not a problem.

Comment: @ErrorPerson: Then you need to explain the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to put a symbol in a string literal that has no equivalent in the keyboard or that can not be accepted directly in the source code. For example, if you need to add a line break in a string, many languages require you to use an equivalent *escape sequence*.

In C/C++, escape sequences are started by a single `\`.  So for example:

- `\n` = Enter
- `\t` = Tab

If you want to use a single `\` in your string literal, you must escape it as `\\`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

In many systems, you can use `/` to separate your path.